# «Мы идём(,) или нет?» Ставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп, частица, или

Ох, столкнулась я с такой трудностью. Трудность, в основном, состоит в том, что, когда правила сопротивляются моему велению и хотению, я начинаю искать в этих правилах брешь, чтобы всё равно писать так, как мне хочется. Есть, к примеру, фраза:

> Мы идём, или нет?

Оба простых предложения в составе сложного — вопросительные. Так почему же мне хочется поставить там запятую? Может, "или нет" — это не простое предложение в составе сложного, а конструкция внутри самого предложения, которая обособляется запятой? И что это тогда за конструкция? Или моя интуиция меня подводит? Растолкуйте мне, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Мы идём или нет?**

Здесь практически нет шансов поставить запятую,  вас просто не поймут. Да и с паузой прочитать это предложение сложно. Поэтому запятая однозначно не ставится хотя бы просто по структуре предложения: **всё читается  в одну фразу с вопросительной интонацией в конце.**

Что касается общей темы вопросительных **сложных** предложений с союзом ИЛИ, то для простоты **классики орфографии не рекомендуют ставить запятую в любом случае,** так как (формально) считают вопросительную интонацию **общим элементом**.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Это кто такие и что им надобно? (П.) — **объединяет вопросительная интонация;** Который теперь час и сколько времени осталось до отхода поезда?; Когда состоится конференция и какова повестка дня?; Вы придёте ко мне или мне прийти к вам?;

С другой стороны,  у авторов появляется естественное желание поделить на части **распространенное предложение** и каждую часть произнести с вопросительной интонацией (и логическим ударением на нужном слове). **Тогда они ставят запятую вопреки правилам.**

https://studfiles.net/preview/6132049/page:53/

МОжешь шагу прибавить, или силЁнок нет? (К. Сим. Живые и мертвые); ПрАвда всё это, или только мерЕщится ему?(Казач. Белое пятно); Что, вы сАми прячетесь, или сЫн вас прячет?(Дост. Идиот).

Answer (score 5):

Запятая в такого рода предложениях не ставится.

Слово НЕТ заменяет глагол-сказуемое НЕ ИДЁМ  во избежание повтора слова ИДЁМ. ***Ср.: Мы идём или не идём?*** В таких конструкциях глагол и слово НЕТ соединяются как однородные члены. ***Ср. Мы идём или остаёмся?***

**НЕТ**. ... При противопоставлении употр. вместо повторения того же сказуемого с отрицанием (разг.). Хочешь жить, как мы, милости просим, нет — так убирайся, проваливай. Пшкн. ***Он приехал или нет?***... [Значение слова НЕТ](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)

Желание поставить запятую объясняется, возможно, тем, что предложения типа ***ИДЁМ ИЛИ НЕТ?*** воспринимаются как сложные, состоящие из двух односоставных, соединённых сочинительным союзом. Но и в этом случае запятая не ставится, ибо обе части вопросительные.

Comment: Спасибо! По поводу запятой усвоила. Но ведь в данном случае _нет_ — Вы сами об этом пишете, — грубо говоря, имеет значение безличного глагола. И тогда это отдельная грамматическая основа, разве нет?

Comment: Посмотрите ссылку. Явление, отражённое в Вашем примере, описано под цифрой 2, а не 1. Там НЕТ трактуется как ОТРИЦ.ЧАСТИЦА, употребляющаяся вместо повторения того же сказуемого с отрицанием.

Comment: Чтобы исключить тавтологию, необязательно использовать такие же конструкции, как и те, которые нам не хочется повторять. Если заменить: "_Он вышел из комнаты, он надел пальто_" - на: "_Он вышел из комнаты и надел пальто_", смысл не изменится, но теперь это уже будет простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми, а не сложносочинённое. То есть грамматически это предложение сильно изменится. Почему здесь это правило не работает?

Answer (score 2):

Если два вопросительных предложения, то требуется два вопросительных знака:

> Мы идем? Или нет?

При произношении между ними будет небольшая пауза.

А если предложение одно, то запятая не требуется.

Comment: Я имела в виду, что оба простых предложения в составе сложного вопросительные.

Answer (score 1):

Как Вы хотите это произнести? Как два вопроса? Тогда так: "Мы идем? Или нет?".

Как один вопрос, без пауз? Тогда так: "Мы идем или нет?". Правила  тут никакой запятой не предусматривают (см. ответы выше).